# Colormap with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What I have tried so far

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap={custom}{color(0)=(red) color(1)=(white) color(2)=(green) color(4)=(blue)},
             colorbar,
    ]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table [row sep=newline] {

0.0000 150.0000 4.578e-10
10.0000 150.0000 4.466e-10
20.0000 150.0000 4.838e-10
30.0000 150.0000 5.657e-10
40.0000 150.0000 6.999e-10
50.0000 150.0000 7.954e-10
60.0000 150.0000 9.443e-10
70.0000 150.0000 1.116e-9
80.0000 150.0000 1.174e-9
90.0000 150.0000 1.162e-9
100.0000 150.0000 1.192e-9
110.0000 150.0000 1.207e-9
120.0000 150.0000 1.259e-9
130.0000 150.0000 1.351e-9
140.0000 150.0000 1.406e-9
150.0000 150.0000 1.432e-9
160.0000 150.0000 1.449e-9
170.0000 150.0000 1.459e-9
180.0000 150.0000 1.465e-9
190.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
200.0000 150.0000 1.463e-9
210.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
220.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
230.0000 150.0000 1.461e-9
240.0000 150.0000 1.457e-9
250.0000 150.0000 1.454e-9
260.0000 150.0000 1.454e-9
270.0000 150.0000 1.456e-9
280.0000 150.0000 1.455e-9
290.0000 150.0000 1.453e-9
0.0000 160.0000 4.617e-10

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My result is this here:

[image: Colormap]

But that is not how I would have it. It should look like this

[image: Example 1 Colormap]

Or at least like this

[image: Example 2 Colormap]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have a lot of points! Nine hundred columns and three rows. The rows start with `0 0 9e-10` and end with `290 290 1.3e-9`.

Hopefully you can help.

Comment: How does your input look like for the checkerboard pattern you need space separated rows

Comment: It would be good to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), including some data.  Maybe you could give us a MWE with a subset of the data (e.g. 10x10 points)?

Comment: Honestly, I'd encourage you to maybe plot this with R (in `ggplot`) or Python (`matplotlib`) and then include the image in LaTeX if you can. It might be easier.

Comment: @jarauh I have included the data. But else it should be a MWE?

Comment: @ArunDebray I couldn't do it in Matplotlib, sadly. But someone [has asked the same question with another data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813519/how-to-make-a-colormap-of-data-in-matplotlib-python). So if she gets an answer, I hopefully will get one too :-)

Comment: I know that I have definitively seen several questions and answers with such "pixelated" output, but at the moment I can't find any. If it is still neccesary, I will have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from `pgfplots.pdf`:

> \addplot3 has a way to decide whether a line visualization or a mesh
>   visualization has to be done.

One has to search a little bit to find out how pgfplots does it in the case of a table input.  To specify a surface, you have to tell `\addplot3` which points are next to each other.  The points are assumed to be in a matrix structure, i.e. `\addplot3` will assume that you have m times n data points, and you have to specify m and n.  Apparently, there are two possibilities:

1. Either you need to specify m or n directly with `mesh/rows` or `mesh/cols`;
2. or you leave empty lines in your table, to indicate where the rows end.

Example (using 2. and copy-paste data):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap={custom}{color(0)=(red) color(1)=(white) color(2)=(green) color(4)=(blue)},
             colorbar,
    ]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table [row sep=newline] {
0.0000 150.0000 4.578e-10
10.0000 150.0000 4.466e-10
20.0000 150.0000 4.838e-10
30.0000 150.0000 5.657e-10
40.0000 150.0000 6.999e-10
50.0000 150.0000 7.954e-10
60.0000 150.0000 9.443e-10
70.0000 150.0000 1.116e-9
80.0000 150.0000 1.174e-9
90.0000 150.0000 1.162e-9
100.0000 150.0000 1.192e-9
110.0000 150.0000 1.207e-9
120.0000 150.0000 1.259e-9
130.0000 150.0000 1.351e-9
140.0000 150.0000 1.406e-9
150.0000 150.0000 1.432e-9
160.0000 150.0000 1.449e-9
170.0000 150.0000 1.459e-9
180.0000 150.0000 1.465e-9
190.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
200.0000 150.0000 1.463e-9
210.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
220.0000 150.0000 1.462e-9
230.0000 150.0000 1.461e-9
240.0000 150.0000 1.457e-9
250.0000 150.0000 1.454e-9
260.0000 150.0000 1.454e-9
270.0000 150.0000 1.456e-9
280.0000 150.0000 1.455e-9
290.0000 150.0000 1.453e-9

0.0000 160.0000 4.617e-10
10.0000 160.0000 4.466e-10
20.0000 160.0000 4.838e-10
30.0000 160.0000 5.657e-10
40.0000 160.0000 6.999e-10
50.0000 160.0000 7.954e-10
60.0000 160.0000 9.443e-10
70.0000 160.0000 1.116e-9
80.0000 160.0000 1.174e-9
90.0000 160.0000 1.162e-9
100.0000 160.0000 1.192e-9
110.0000 160.0000 1.207e-9
120.0000 160.0000 1.259e-9
130.0000 160.0000 1.351e-9
140.0000 160.0000 1.406e-9
150.0000 160.0000 1.432e-9
160.0000 160.0000 1.449e-9
170.0000 160.0000 1.459e-9
180.0000 160.0000 1.465e-9
190.0000 160.0000 1.462e-9
200.0000 160.0000 1.463e-9
210.0000 160.0000 1.462e-9
220.0000 160.0000 1.462e-9
230.0000 160.0000 1.461e-9
240.0000 160.0000 1.457e-9
250.0000 160.0000 1.454e-9
260.0000 160.0000 1.454e-9
270.0000 160.0000 1.456e-9
280.0000 160.0000 1.455e-9
290.0000 160.0000 1.453e-9

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: final heatmap]

Comment: thank you very much! But I have a last question: how do I get a unit after the "10e-9"? I have tried with 'colorbar style={title=Color key, align=right}' - but the title appears at the top of "10^-9" and not behind it. How to fix it? The unit is an "A".

Comment: The "10e-9" is called a multiplier.  I don't know if its format can be changed, but if you search the pgfplots manual for multiplier you should be able to find it.  If not, you could ask a new question.